# Folder is not visible in localhost

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have downloaded a web template and when i try to run that in my localhost the folder doesn't show up.that folder contains a .htaccess file.When i remove that file i can see the folder but when i open that it gives some errors.

This is the .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine On   
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f  
RewriteRule ^$ index.php [L]  
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)?$ user-profile.php?user_username=$1 [NC,L]
```

this is the first time i'm working with a .htaccess file...
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What is your question? Are you expecting to see a directory listing or something? If you access the folder directly ie. `/folder/` then the request is routed to `index.php`. So, you should be seeing whatever `index.php` outputs. If you don't see anything - then that could well be the intention.

Comment: I can't see the folder in localhost index page...when i try to access using `localhost/folder/index.php` it shows an internal server error.

Comment: The fact that "when you remove that file" you also get "some errors" is a bit suspect. It makes me think something else is not configured correctly. Is .htaccess / mod_rewrite working as expected in other parts of the site?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe problem in the index.php file PHP code? Rewrite rules looks fine.

Show us the Apache error log and a rewrite log, without that hard to say what is wrong.

Comment: Apache error log
`[Thu Sep 24 19:38:18.579561 2015] [core:alert] [pid 2828:tid 1100] [client ::1:9042] C:/wamp/www/New folder/UserProf/.htaccess: Invalid command 'RewriteEngine', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration`

I don't have a rewrite log file

Comment: You have to [enable mod_rewrite](http://www.webdevdoor.com/php/mod_rewrite-windows-apache-url-rewriting/) module.

Comment: Thank you very much enabling that module worked for me

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the `RewriteCond` directive is in the wrong place...? I would have thought it should apply to the 2nd `RewriteRule`, not the first:

```
RewriteEngine On   
RewriteRule ^$ index.php [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f  
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)?$ user-profile.php?user_username=$1 [NC,L]
```

`RewriteCond` directives apply to the single `RewriteRule` that follows. That 2nd ruleset basically says that if the requested file does not exist then internally rewrite the request to the `user-profile.php` page passing the request (which is assumed to be a *username*) to the `user_username` parameter.

Comment: tried swapping the lines..but still i can't go to index.php

Comment: What happens exactly when you navigate to `/folder/index.php`? What does `index.php` contain?

Comment: when I navigate to index page this is what i can see now..

Internal Server Error

The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

index.php contains a simple form to register an user.